# Missing operating system

Tags: windows-7

I had windows 8 on my pc and i wanted to install ubuntu instead And after installing it and reboting a messege in the boot black screen says ( Missing operating system ) That's my first use for ubuntu (Any help !! ) please .

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu? Try to be as specific as possible. Can you use either a live CD or USB drive?

Comment: using usb stick

Comment: Can you follow [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info) to run the boot-info-script. You don't have to run the repair options (yet). Let us first have a look at the output of the boot-info pastebin. So please give us the URL when you are done.